# How to make custom commands with batch?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, echo, goto, pause

I am working on making my own custom command prompt of sorts to make it easier to get things done. I've successfully created the interface and a `type` command, but when I tried adding a `help` command, it echoes the menu, but my `pause >nul` i put in doesn't work, the window just closes. Can you take a look, and help me out?
Thanks in advance!

```
@echo off
:HELLO
echo Hello!
pause >nul
cls
echo What can I do for you? Type in your commmand! (Type "help" to display a list of every command available.)
set /p command=
if %command%==type (
goto :TYPEFILENAME
)
if %command%==help (
goto :HELPLIST
)
:MAIN
cls
echo What can I do for you? Type in your commmand! (Type "help" to display a list of every command available.)
set /p command=
if %command%==type (
goto :TYPEFILENAME
)
if %command%==help (
goto :HELPLIST
)
pause >nul
:HELPLIST
echo ----------------------------------
echo Help: Page 1/1
echo Command | What it does
echo help    | displays this page
echo type    | types a file
echo ----------------------------------
pause >nul
goto :MAIN
```

If you need the rest of the code, tell me! This is what I think is most important, so I didn't add in the rest.

Comment: Quick note: You should open a command prompt first, and then execute your file from there. This will prevent the closing and you can read potential error messages. You can open a command prompt in a directory when shift-rightclicking in the explorer window and then select "open command prompt here".

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I did that, it gave me this error message `'What' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` I can't figure it out.

Comment: Escape the pipe symbol in the echo with a caret `^|`

Comment: @LotPings Thank you! That was the problem!

Comment: Why do you have the exact same code twice?  Why not three or four times?  The more the better, right?

Comment: @MikeNakis I have that because when you open the file, it will say "Hello!" However, I don't want that to display afterwards. I know I could just use `goto :MAIN` after the `echo Hello!`, but I had already done it this way when I noticed, so I kept it.

Comment: I understand, but keep in mind that when you are asking people to read your code and figure out what's wrong with it, it helps to not frustrate them by having them read unnecessary junk code, (as in junk DNA,) and making them read it again a few times trying to figure out whether the two blocks are in fact identical or whether they differ in some minute little detail that is hard to notice.  It is tiresome and it is not appreciated.

Comment: @MikeNakis OK, your comment actually did make me decide to change it, so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing why the Help part is crashing, is the bar (|) character.
When you want to echo special like this, you have to add an escape character (^) in front of them.
That part of your code should be like this:

```
echo ----------------------------------
echo Help: Page 1/1
echo Command ^| What it does
echo help    ^| displays this page
echo type    ^| types a file
echo ----------------------------------
```